# Dock icons disappear and/or go fuzzy

Tags: dock, icon

Every now and then the icons in my Dock disappear completely after waking from sleep, except some of them go funny or fuzzy. See screenshot.

MacBook Pro Retina, 15", Mid 2014, i7, 16GB memory, often plugged into a Dell P2715Q 4K Display. El Capitan.

I've tried `killall Dock` in terminal to no avail, and rebooting doesn't do anything much.

Any thoughts on what's causing this, or how to force OS X to clear its cache of the icons or similar?

[image: Dock with fuzzy and missing icons]

Answer (score 1):

To clear the cache you need to delete the dock's **plist**.

Go to `~/Library/Preferences` and delete `com.apple.dock.plist`.  Restart your Mac.  That should rebuild the icons.  I'm not sure why this is happening, maybe someone else here can help with that.

Comment: I've done this, but the icons for Slack, MS Word, and Terminal are still missing. :-(

Comment: Don't do this if you've made any modifications to your Dock settings (e.g., changing what programs are there, disabling Siri/Launchpad, etc)— since it will reset things to the factory-default Dock settings!